# Why is it supposedly bad practice to declare a variable in the private part of a class? C++

Tags: c++, class

I'm taking advanced C++ this semester in College, and I keep running into needing my work re-submitted because I'm using bad practice of declaring a variable without using mutator methods to set them.

I'm told that using code like this is bad practice.

```
class test{
private:
   int number = 5;
   int number2 = 10;
public:
   int addNums(){
       number3 = number+number2;
       return number3;}
};
```

My instructor recommends I should use declaration like this.

```
class test{
private:
   int number, number2;
public:
   void setNums(userInput, userInput2){//Where user input is gained from a seperate function setting as 5, 10.
       number = userInput;
       number2 = userInput2;}
   int addNums(){
       number3 = number+number2;
       return number3;}
};
```

Why is it bad practice to have a pre-defined variable when the program doesn't require user input? I mean, I can understand doing that if the user needs to put a number for the items, and then I would have done just this, but if it doesn't ask for user input, I'm not going to have user input.

Comment: Does your code even compile? It's a compilation error to initialize class members within the class. You must use the constructor to initialize the same as recommended by your instructor.

Comment: Apart from the inability for the posted code to compile (neither does), there's nothing wrong with the first code approach so long as you have no interest in any of the integers between INT_MIN and INT_MAX other than `5` and `10`. If you do, obviously the former has it's drawbacks.

Comment: @Vishal The second definitely won't compile, but the first only has the missing type of `number3` to declare. [The initializers work](http://ideone.com/Q1wgut).

Comment: Why not `struct test { static constexpr int addNums() { return 15; } };`

Comment: To the ones saying the code doesn't compile, I wrote it as Psuedo code, as an example

Comment: Why would you have member variables with no way to set them? In your first block how do you apply the user input?

Comment: M.M It's not required to have user input, but I guess she wanted it

Comment: I would argue that the need for setters is often a sign of inadequate design modelling pure data objects. The class should represent a concise idea with a defined responsibility, and the interface should offer services which manage the internal state. A setter leads to a design where the state is managed outside the class. However, the example is a little bit too small to really say something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instructor is telling you to take just that minimal investment to making your class significantly more usable.

> I mean, I can understand doing that if the user needs to put a number for the items, and then I would have done just this, but if it doesn't ask for user input, I'm not going to have user input.

And here you acknowledge that it would have the desired effect.

The question to ask yourself when designing is "what would my users expect?" Would reasonable users of that class expect that there is no way to pass in numbers? I think your instructor's answer to that is "no". I'm leaning that way as well.

Note that hardcoded inputs in your *program* are okay by the same logic. Would reasonable users of your program expect that there is no way to pass in numbers? Yes, that is exactly what the user asked for.

Comment: So what I'm getting from this, is even though user input is not required, it is generally thought to be true? Like, I should add it even if not required? If so, then yea, I can get this np. Thanks for the extra insight :)

Comment: From your class's perspective, yeah, that's a good way of looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that setters are often a sign of bad design because they enable decisions about the objects state being made outside the class. In your (too) simple example, I would initialize the variables in the constructor:

```
class test{
private:
   int number;
   int number2;
public:
   test(int x, int y):
      number(x), number2(y) {}

   test(): test(5, 10) {}

   int addNums(){
       return number+number2;
   }
};
```

However, nobody knows what the test class should do or what responsibility it has. It may be better to change `addNums` to take two parameters, and remove the members completely.

Comment: interesting sounding concept, but I'm not quite sure I follow your example. That stuff isn't anything we've covered yet, I'm sure a simple google would help me find out what it is, but currently I don't understand. However, I understand that in the class I posted, has no real use apart from giving you 15 as a result, if I posted something particularly useful it would be easier to get a solid answer.

Comment: You could entirely remove `number3`, which is an error in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Does the class make any sense, if no user input is provided?

If yes, the pre-defined values *may* make sense as well. Although as it stands they're just magic numbers chosen *because*.

If not, the class object should not be creatable at all. Make sure the only way to construct is via a ctor, requiring the values.

If you wish, you may add default values to the ctor as well, although that is mixing the two approaches, and in fact is similar to default values provided at declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental design question you have to ask yourself is "what is the purpose of this class"?

As written, it has a member function named `addNums()` that **always** returns the value 15 (assuming that `number3` has been declared somewhere. If that's its purpose, there's far too much mechanism; the member function should simply return 15, and if that's all it does, it's name should be changed because it doesn't add any numbers.

On the other hand, if the purpose of the class is to hold two values and return their sum, there has to be some way to set the values, either through the constructor or through some sort of member function. Once there's a way to set the values, `addNums()` does something useful, as its name suggests.